# if condition accepting capitalized string in python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, conditional-statements, equation

Considering the following construct that controls strings:

```
if input_ == "Option1":
    print "Option 1"
elif input_ == "Option2":
    print "Option 2"
else:
    print "Option x"
```

Is there any way to make Option1 and Option2 to accept any capitalized characters (such as "option1", "OpTion1", "OPTION1" etc...)?

Comment: You should consider letting your users just type `1` or `2` without forcing them to type "option" every time.

Comment: I added numbers to make it easier for you to read. I need the users to write different words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convert the input to a single case, then compare that.

```
input_ = input_.lower()
if input_ == "option1":
    print "Option 1"
elif input_ == "option2":
    print "Option 2"
else:
    print "Option x"
```